# What is this grass-like plant?

Tags: identification, grass

What is this plant? I could not find anything.

[image]

[image]

Comment: As this grass gets older you should see glints of orange at the ends of the leaves.  Absolutely gorgeous in big groupings.  Not as invasive as mexican feather grass but you'll find babies popping up now and then.  At the price these go for, you'll want to transplant them into your landscape.  Let us know when you see seed heads or coloring.  Definitely a garden plant versus indoors.  Perfect for spicing up your potted plants.  Prune by gathering straight up into a 'pony tail' and cut straight across, release and ta da!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is too young to tell right now over a photo.  I've got two others that I dearly love, one being voraciously invasive but hell...that is Mexican Feather Grass; Stipa tenuissima.  The other is Orange Sedge; Carex testacea.  I looked up the pics on the internet and I disagree with the pictures of Orange sedge...light green with orange tints, tips.  This plant is not bronze at all!![![Carex testacea
][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/baAuq.jpg)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/baAuq.jpg)

Answer (score 2):

Judging by its upright habit, maybe Calamagrostis 'Karl Foerster' without its flowers/seedheads http://plants.gertens.com/12070009/Plant/2170/Karl_Foerster_Reed_Grass, otherwise Carex elata 'Aurea', though that one has leaves which tend to curl over gracefully.

A clearer image, without a plant directly behind it, which shows more detail of the foliage might confirm or deny the ID.

UPDATE - its not Carex, so more likely Calamagrostis, which is commonly known as a reed grass. Hard to be certain without the presence of flowers or seedheads though, and if its been indoors for some months, that makes it harder - Calamagrostis usually dies back in winter in cooler regions, but won't have done that indoors - its not usually grown as a houseplant.